# How to connect Drupal securely to Nodejs socket.io

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, drupal, socket.io

I'm having an Apache Server with Drupal on it. (here are the user credentials)

I also have a nodejs Server with socket.io on it. (couchbase db: here are additional user information. I want to connect with the Drupal's one)

Trivia: They're both on the same machine.

How do I securely connect a user from Drupal to the appropriate user
in nodejs?

I dont want user A from Drupal to get to the user Information at nodejs from user B

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Drupal authentication strategy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-drupal) for [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) to authenticate user in your NodeJS application.

Check also the NodeJS module][3](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs) for Drupal. It provides an API for modules (ie. PHP code), to sent real time messages to the user (using NodeJS and socket.io).